# How do I remove the white blank space between the paragraph and the footer?

Tags: html, css

Visit the url [file:///Users/CatherineDu/百度云同步盘/practice/about.html] I am new to html and css, trying to build a simple website here. I keep getting these white spaces between my paragraph ending and the footer, the blank space is about 2cm wide? I tried fixing the margin or set margin-bottom to zero but nothing worked.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <hmtl>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title> The Tailory New York </title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
            <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Anton|Crimson+Text:400,700,700i|Rakkas" rel="stylesheet">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
        </head>   
        <body>
            <header>
               <div id="logo">
               <a href="index.html">
               <img src="img/logo_The Tailory New York_black.png" alt="">
               </div>
                <nav> 
                    <ul>
                        <li> <a href="home.html">Home </a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="app.html">Appointment </a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="gallery.html">Gallery </a></li>
                        <li> <a href="about.html"class="selected">About</a></li>
                        <li> <a href="contact.html" >Contact </a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav> 
            </header>
                    <section>
                    <img src="img/profile.jpg" alt="" class="profile_photo">
                    <div class="profile">
                    <h1>ABOUT</h1>
                            <h2>The Brand</h2>
                                <p>
                                    The Tailory New York is an appointment only custom clothing company that combines the modernity of Fashion Design with the heritage art of Custom Tailoring. We are unique in that we cater to both the Men and Women market.
                                </p>
                            <h2>The Concept </h2>
                                <p>
                                    Providing personally designed, fitted and curated collections for each individual client is the essence of who we are. At The Tailory New York, we believe that your wardrobe should not only fit perfectly, but should be designed with only YOU in mind. The end result?—clients get the best of both worlds, impeccable custom fit and custom designed pieces that works seamlessly with their lifestyle.
                                </p>
                            <h2>A Note From the Founder</h2>
                                <p>
                                    The idea for The Tailory New York began when I decided to direct my years of fashion design and men’s tailoring experience towards my own wardrobe. As a pant suit aficionado and a lover of men’s fashion and tailoring, I was always drawn to tailored clothing and strived to create fashion that conveyed the same message of confidence that a perfectly custom tailored suit did for men. Style icons like Sean Connery and Cary Grant, as well as modern day 007 Daniel Craig (shaken not stirred) were always my style inspirations. To me, they are the epitome of refinement and sophistication, true gentlemen in style.
                                    My passion for fashion and tailoring led me through the Fashion Design program at Parsons followed by stints in custom tailoring, fashion design, fashion styling and brand development. But the more I integrated myself in the industry, the more I realized that impeccable fit, for men and women, was almost impossible to find in ready to wear clothing. So, I launched The Tailory New York, a way for me to combine my two passions, Fashion Design and Custom Tailoring. Everyone wants to look their best and having a wardrobe curated to your body and lifestyle not only enables you to look your best but makes you feel your best.
                                    At The Tailory New York, “we believe that your wardrobe should not only fit perfectly, but should be designed with only YOU in mind.” Providing personally designed, fitted and curated collections for each individual client is the essence of who we are. Let us curate and design the wardrobe fit for YOU! </br>
                                    <br> </br>
                                    Sincerely,</br>
                                    Shao Yang, Founder 
                                    <br> </br>
                                </p> 
                                </div>

                    </section>          
                </body>

                <div id="social_media">
                    <footer>
                        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/thetailorynewyork"> <img src="img/facebook.jpg" alt="Facebook logo" class="social-icon"> </a>
                        <a href="https://www.twitter.com/thetailorynewyork"> <img src="img/twitter.png" alt="Twitter logo"class="social-icon"></a>
                        <a href="https://www.instagram.com/thetailorynyc"> <img src="img/instagram.jpeg" alt="Instagram logo"class="social-icon"> </a> </br>
                        &copy; 2017 The Tailory New York All Rights Reserved 
                    </footer>
            </div>


    /****************************************
    GENERAL
    *****************************************/
    a {
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    img{
        max-width: 100%;
    }




    /****************************************
        BACKGROUND ANIMATION
    ****************************************/
    section ul{
        list-style: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    #selector{
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    /***************************************
    HEADER
    ***************************************/


    /* header black*/
    header{
        background: black;
    }


    /* black header using the Tailory's logo*/
    #logo{
        text-align:center;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0 5%
    }


    /* nav links black */
    nav{
        background: black;
    }

    nav ul{
        list-style: none;
        margin: 0 10px;
        padding: 0;
        text-align: center;
    }

    nav li{
        display: inline-block; 
    }

    /* nav link and visited link white*/
    nav a{
        font-weight: 800;
        padding: 15px 10px;
        color: white;
        font-family: 'Crimson Text', sans-serif;
        font-size: 1.25m;
    }
    nav a:link{
        color: white;
    }
    nav a:visited{
        color: grey;
    }
```

/***************************************
        FOOTER
        ***************************************/

```
    footer{
        font-size: 1em;
        text-align: center;
        clear: both;
        padding: 50px 50px;
        color: white;
        background-color: grey;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    .social-icon{
        width: 20px;
        height: 20px;
        margin: 0 5px;
    }
    /***************************************
    PAGE: ABOUT
    ***************************************/
    h1{
        margin: 0 0 1.5em 0;
        font-family: 'Rakkas','sans-serif';
        font-weight: 500;
    }

    h2{
        margin: 0 0 1.2em 0;
        font-family: 'Rakkas', 'sans-serif';
        font-weight: normal;
    }

    .profile{
        color: grey;
        background-color: black;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    .profile_photo{
        display: block;
        max-width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
```

Comment: The "URL" points to your local file system. Btw, I'd recommend using some tool like Chrome Dev Tools, then inspect element, to see exactly what is happening in that "blank space".

Comment: make the last `p` tag `margin:0;` at the section

Comment: [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/29s01dd7/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#social_media` is outside of `</body>` - you need to keep all of your HTML inside `<body></body>`.

But you just need to remove the bottom margin from the last paragraph in your `.profile` section. You can do it with this CSS.

```
.profile p:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

Here's a demo http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LxEbWv

Comment: Thank you so much! Can you explain what last-child is?

Comment: @Catherine `:last-child` selects the `p` that appears as the "last" element amongst its siblings. I.e. it's the last-child of its immediate parent.

Answer (score -1):

Add this to your `#social_media` :

```
margin-top: -16px;
```